# Unable to start kairosdb on windows 7

Tags: cassandra, opentsdb, cassandra-cli, kairosdb

I am new to Cassandra and Kairos. I am unable to start kairosdb on my windows system. 
    Steps I followed:
    I installed Cassandra and from cqlsh window I added a keyspace kairosdb (source: http://prasannasjain.blogspot.in/2014/05/time-series-database-kairos-db-with.html)
    Then I installed kairosdb from https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb/releases and pointed the database to Cassandra in kairosdb.properties file

```
Issue:
I tried starting kairosdb using commands "kairosdb.sh start" from command line and "./kairosdb.sh start" from Git Bash. The error I am getting is 
./kairosdb.sh: line 49: /var/run/kairosdb.pid: No such file or directory

Please suggest what is wrong here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in the command prompt window:

```
kairosdb.bat run
```

Answer (score -1):

Run it under root, like this:

```
sudo kairosdb.sh start
```